# C# How can I get the caller member name of the caller?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement an [Enumeration class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) and I'd like to make the `Name` field automatically assigned in the constructor of this class.

Here's the working class which I want to improve as well as an example subclass:

```cs
public abstract class Enumeration<E> : IComparable where E : Enumeration<E>
{
    public readonly int Id;
    public readonly string Name;

    private static int _count;
    protected Enumeration(string name)
    {
        Id = _count++;

        Name = name;
    }

    // etc
}

public class Color : Enumeration<Color>
{
    public readonly static Color Red = new Color(1, 0, 0);
    public readonly static Color Green = new Color(0, 1, 0);
    public readonly static Color Blue = new Color(0, 0, 1);

    public readonly float R;
    public readonly float G;
    public readonly float B;

    private Color(float r, 
                  float g, 
                  float b,
                  // I wanna move this to super
                  [CallerMemberName]
                  string name="") : base(name)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }

    // etc
}
```

So is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish? In your example, if I refer to `Color.Red.Name`, what is the value you want?

Comment: Yea I mean your code just works fine. Having `[CallerMemberName]` just in your base abstract `Enumeration` class won't work if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I would like `Name` to be automatically set, just as `Id` is. `[CallerMemberName]` indeed does not work inside of `Enumeration` because its caller is the constructor of `Color`, so I need the Member Name of the Caller of the Caller.

Maybe I'm asking how `[CallerMemberName]` gets its value, because I can't find the information in the stack trace.

Comment: This seems pretty confusing, as `Color` is explicitly *not* an enumeration, but a class with three properties. That you could *also* have a collection of pre-defined colors seems another matter entirely. Implicitly incrementing a `static` field this way is a *really bad idea*, because the order in which initializers are run is defined only within a class, and even then you have to know it's in lexical order (top to bottom). Woe betide anyone who actually uses `Id` as a value stored outside a single run of the process!

Comment: I can rename `Id` to `_hashcode` and make it private

Comment: If all you're really using it for is a hash, it'd be tons better to actually have a proper hash, based on `R`, `G` and `B` -- that way `Red` and `new Color(1, 0, 0)` could compare equal even if I didn't know you had a pre-defined `Red`. If you actually do want to hash based just on the specific instance you don't need to do anything special; `Object.GetHashCode` already has you covered there. Also, consider leveraging `ValueTuple` -- `(float red, float green, float blue)` has all these things built-in, and you can map names to instances with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that would get you the name for free, but you would have to use `int` type for the RGB values (not really sure why you are using float anyways, they are supposed to be integers):

```
private Color(int r, int g, int b):base(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r, g, b).Name)
{                        
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
}
```

However, it seems like a code smell to me, at least with your current implementation. I am not sure why you want to create this instead of just using the .NET `Color` type but that is none of my business.

Please note that this will (obviously) break with an `ArgumentException` if you pass RGBs that don't make sense. Also, make sure to account for unknown colors (this will only work with known ones).

Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to remove the need for the `Name` property to be manually set, just as `Id` is.

Comment: @Hullaballoonatic: That is an internal detail of the implementation. If you don't set it, who will? You have to do it at some point. I've given you a way to somewhat automate this with the `nameof` construct. The only other alternative, as I mentioned in my answer is to keep an internal dictionary of colors that you can pick based on the RGB but that is somewhat of a code smell.

Comment: @Hullaballoonatic: I just thought of something else. Hang tight. I will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Hullaballoonatic: Take another read. I think this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, It's close and actually the annotation `[CallerMemberName]` is able to handle that much all its own. What I'd like to do is basically eliminate any need for this step from a subclass

Comment: @Hullaballoonatic: You are not making a lot of sense.